# find / select specified ID in array php

Tags: php, arrays

i have array with database, and have to select only this items what have "tid" = 1

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["tid"]=> "1"
    ["title"]=> "Google"
    ["url"]=> "http://google.com/"
    ["description"]=> "A very efficient search engine."
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["tid"]=> "2"
    ["title"]=> "Facebook"
    ["url"]=> "http://facebook.com/"
    ["description"]=> "Trade securities, currently supports nearly 1000 stocks and ETFs"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["tid"]=> "1"
    ["title"]=> "Yandex"
    ["url"]=> "http://yandex.ru/"
    ["description"]=> "Another efficient search engine popular in Russia"
  }
}
```

how can i select only this items from array what have "tid" = 1?

Comment: Why not just pull only what you need from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filteredArray = array();

for($i = 0, $end = count($array);$i < $end;i++)
{ 

    if($array[$i]["tid"] === "1") 
    {
       $filderedArray[] = $array[$i];
    }
 }
```

That way $filteredArray will contain solely the items with tid 1;

Comment: this is not even php but some weird mix

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'm used to C#, and my php has been fading away ever since I graduated. I edited the answer as you suggested. Thanks for making my answer even better!

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$final_arr = array();
foreach($tid_arrs as $tid_arr){
    if($tid_arr['tid'] == 1){
        $final_arr[] = $tid_arr;
    }
}

print_r($final_arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try array_filter function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php this should help.

```
print_r(array_filter($array, "filter_function"));

function filter_function($element){
    return (int)$element['tid'] === 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say you starting array is $arr.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $arrItem) {
  if ((array_key_exists('tid', $arrItem)) && ($arrItem['tid'] == "1")){
     $result[] =  $arrItem;
  }
}
```

$result should be what you are excepted.